# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

How come this code throws an "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"?
I have checked that the javascript is able to be loaded. But the firebug always showing the error message.
Here is the html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />   
<title>Lab 2</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "lab2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id= "chatHeader"><h1>Lab2 - (not yet online) Chat</h1></div>
<div id= "chatContentArea"> 
</div>
<div id= "chatBottomBar">
        <textarea>Leave your message</textarea>
        <button>submit</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var message = $('textarea').val();
        alert(message);
    })
});
```

Comment: Where are you loading the `jQuery` library?

Comment: have you included jQuery library file http://jquery.com/download/ ??

Comment: @TusharGupta Sorry, I am new to JQuery, shall i add <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> before loading my own js?

Comment: +1 no reason to go on a downvote frenzy to someone who's new to jquery or any other language for that matter. It's just rude

Comment: @bicycle not a downvoter, but with a quick search on google or on related post can be found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include this on your page **before the beginning of your jQuery code**...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be in the `head`

Comment: No, but it does have to be before the `$(document).ready` line

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include jQuery, happens a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your page:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

usually put this towards the bottom of the page so it loads quicker...HTH